# Error in progress bar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have an error in a progress bar.

This is a code:

```
public class BluetoothChat extends Activity {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
private static final boolean D = true;

private int progressStatus = 0;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

// Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

// Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

// Layout Views
private ListView mConversationView;
private EditText mOutEditText;
private Button mSendButton;
private Button mvc;

// Name of the connected device
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
// Array adapter for the conversation thread
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
// String buffer for outgoing messages
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
// Local Bluetooth adapter
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
// Member object for the chat services
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
private ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

mvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (progressStatus < 1000) {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int i1 = r.nextInt(1000);
                        if (i1 > progressStatus){
                            progressStatus = i1;
                        }
                        else {
                            progressStatus = progressStatus;
                        }
                        // Update the progress bar and display the current value in the text view
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            // Sleep for 200 milliseconds. Just to display the progress slowly
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

This is a logcat:

```
      02-15 12:14:14.102: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(21179): Parent view is not a TextView
      02-15 12:14:14.142: D/AndroidRuntime(21179): Shutting down VM
      02-15 12:14:14.142: W/dalvikvm(21179): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught            exception (group=0x418ca898)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.example.android.BluetoothChat/com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothC          hat}: java.lang.NullPointerException
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.onCreate(BluetoothChat.java:98)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
      02-15 12:14:14.142: E/AndroidRuntime(21179):  ... 11 more
      02-15 12:14:16.534: I/Process(21179): Sending signal. PID: 21179 SIG: 9
```

the application does not start, can anyone help me understand the problem? Thank you!
P.S if I remove the button still works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreate(), Need to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

or your layout name -the xml where your "button1" is...

before

```
mvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

It helps your activity to identify its layout and where to look for the components with `findViewById`

Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)

http://bloggerinme.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/android-programming-setcontentview/

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
```

in your `onCreate` method. You have declared a variable but isn't initialized it. And you should have use

```
setContentView();
```

to set the layout for the activity. Here is the doc for that [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)

Line drawn from doc is :-

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a complex view hierarchy.